# (Postgresql) make table trigger function insert ID value of changed row into log table, for custom replication

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-replication, multi-master-replication

For Postgresql---and eventually Sybase ADS---I have tables that will replicate using homemade triggers. The triggers have a function which should record info for INSERT UPDATE DELETE changes which include the I/U/D operation and the ID of the row that changed. I am using test tables with a first name column and auto incrementing ID to test bidirectional replication.

If I make an insert to the NAME table such as adding 'JOHN' with an autoID of '1', am I able to insert that ID value and even possibly 'JOHN' into a log table? I am looking at the OLD.ID or NEW.ID options but I don't know if that's how it can work. My trigger/function code is:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $ReplInsert$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO "log" ("Operation","ID","NAME")
    VALUES ('DELETE', OLD.ID, OLD.NAME);
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO "log" ("Operation","ID","NAME")
    VALUES ('UPDATE', NEW.ID ,NEW.NAME);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO "log" ("Operation","ID","NAME")
    VALUES ('UPDATE', NEW.ID , NEW.NAME);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; 
    END;
$ReplInsert$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logTrg
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "FIRST_NAME"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE Insert();
```

This is ultimately to make bidirectional replication using triggers. Thank you for any consideration or guidance. I will edit as needed.

Comment: Don’t quote the old and new values that you want to insert. If you put them in quotes, you will literally be inserting the string of ‘NEW.ID’ instead of the new id.

Comment: @Nate Sorry, typo mistake on my part. edited. My code didn't have quotes around the NEW and OLD NAME and ID value entries; just the operation values. I still get ERROR:  record "new" has no field "id" which I am troubleshooting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing AFTER to BEFORE in the trigger, which I believed at first wouldn't work, or:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $ReplInsert$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO "log" ("Operation","ID","NAME")
    VALUES ('DELETE', OLD.ID, OLD.NAME);
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO "log" ("Operation","ID","NAME")
    VALUES ('UPDATE', NEW.ID ,NEW.NAME);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO "log" ("Operation","ID","NAME")
    VALUES ('UPDATE', NEW.ID , NEW.NAME);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; 
    END;
$ReplInsert$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logTrg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON "FIRST_NAME"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE Insert();
```